# Highlighting a button from another class in objective-C, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have an app that includes a bluetooth LE class for handling a BT connection. When a characteristic value is changed I want code in the BT class to change a button state on the main viewcontroller. I'm new to obj-c and usually use stackoverflow to help with my understanding. I have the following defined in my viewcontroller:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *eraseButton;
```

within the view controller, I can happily change the button state:

```
[self.eraseButton setHidden:YES];
```

and

```
-(void) deselectEraseButton
{
    [self.eraseButton setSelected:NO];
}
```

within the BT class I have tried many things (changing a property of viewcontroller which changes the button state via a timer, calling a method that directly changes the button state etc) and although the code is executed (I have breakpoints set on the code in myViewController), the button state isn't changed. For example:

```
myAppDelegate *app = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            app.vCtrl=[[myViewController alloc] init];
            [app.vCtrl deselectEraseButton];
```

What am I doing wrong and what's the best way of doing this? I'm sure it shouldn't be this hard!

**UPDATE:**

with the help of Zhi-Wei Cai (thanks), I'm made some changes but alas, it's still not working:

I added the following to myAppDelegate.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) myViewController* vCtrl;
```

I added the following to myAppDelegate.m:

```
-(void)eraseButton:(BOOL)state{
    [vCtrl accessEraseButton:state];
}
```

From the BT class, I do the following:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(test) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

with the following method in that class:

```
-(void) test
    {
        myAppDelegate *app = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [app eraseButton:0];
}
```

This called myViewController and on thread1 did the following:

```
-(void) accessEraseButton: (BOOL) state
{
    if (state==0)
    {
        [self.eraseButton setSelected:NO];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.eraseButton setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

I then added `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` for good luck. The button is still not changing state but the code is running (I can hit a breakpoint and it breaks on the method and the method is running on thread1)?!? Any ideas?

*** UPDATE 2 ***

Ok, I've worked out what I was doing wrong. I was doing all of the above without properly referencing the viewcontroller. So although the code was executing, the instance of the viewcontroller wasn't correct and all the button handles were nil. I needed to add the following to myViewController.m, in viewDidLoad:

```
myAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.myViewController = self;
```

Now it works. Happy days...

Comment: http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do `app.vCtrl = [[myViewController alloc] init];`, you actually created a new instance of the `UIViewController`, not the original one that's on your screen.

I didn't test them, but you can achieve what you wanted by:

- **Via Interface Builder:** Setup an `IBOutlet` of the `UIViewController` in your `myAppDelegate`, connect it to the ViewController within Interface Builder, then create a method in `myAppDelegate` to change it or access it directly using `myAppDelegate` as it's a property. You can now call it within your BT class e.g. `[app deselectEraseButton]` or `[app.myViewController deselectEraseButton]` or even do something with the button if the button is a property of the AppDelegate/VC.
- **Via Delegate:** Create a `@protocol` to setup a **delegate** for the BT class, so the it can do callback within other classes such as `myAppDelegate`.
- **Via NSNotificationCenter:** Use `- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender` and `- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` to do it. This will work app-wide.

I believe the above three already has tons of code example on SO, just search them and you will get what you need.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and quick reply. I thought that perhaps the missing piece was the method code in myAppDelegate. I've done that and I get the same problem - the code is executed in myViewController but the button state doesn't change. Is there a reason why the code could be executed but the button doesn't change state? I did also try the notificationcenter method but this seemed a bit slow - the button only changed state after around 5-10 seconds after the BT method completed.

Comment: Check if you did all UI changes within the main thread? or try use `setNeedsDisplay` to do force update see if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated by original question with 2 updates that lead to a final understanding and solution. Hope it helps others who may be similarly confused!